# chmod 014 directory listing permissions

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, directory, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Say I login as `root` and create a directory

```
> mkdir /mydir
```

Now I create a group `mygroup`

```
> groupadd mygroup
```

Then I add a user `someuser` to the group `mygroup`

```
> usermod -a -G mygroup someuser
```

Next I assign the directory `/mydir` to the group `mygroup`

```
> chgrp mygroup /mydir
```

Finally I update the permissions of `/mydir` to `014`:

```
> chmod 014 /mydir
```

What I'm wondering is when I log in as `someuser` and attempt to `ls /mydir` why do I get a permission error on wsl2 ubuntu. My limited understanding is that group should have execute (traverse) permissions for the directory and the world (aka other) should have read permissions. Since `someuser` is a part of both the world and the group `mygroup` wouldn't `someuser` have both read and execute permissions for `/mydir`?

If not, why? Do permissions short circuit from most specific scope to least?

Thanks!

Comment: You have the short circuit correct. `someuser` matches the group is that account has only execute permissions. World permissions are not looked at. More sane permissions may be `0750` on the directory.

Comment: Short summary - *"Other"* does not equate to *"World"*.  Other means *"not the user and not in the group"*.

Comment: thanks folks, @NotTheDr01ds explanation of the other bits really helps me understand the short circuit behavior. Much appreciated.